# deficiency indices

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

Let the deficiency indices of a closed symmetric operator $A$ be
$$n_+ = ker(A^*-iI), n_- = ker(A^*+iI)$$
and $A$ can be expanded to be self-adjoint iff $n_+ = n_-$, even if both indices is (countably) infinity.
My question is, is this holds with uncountably infinity? And what if one is countable but the other isn't?
Thanks for help!

Comment: I believe you forgot a “$\operatorname{dim}$” – deficiency indices are the *dimension* of the respective kernels.

Comment: Most of the time, you'll work in **separable spaces** which (by definition) have a countable basis. Hence you can never have *uncountably* infinite deficiency indices in a separable space. Sadly, I don't have any experience with non-separable spaces, so I can't tell you how deficiency indices work there.

Comment: Self-adjoint extension exists if and only if $n_+ = n_-$ as cardinal numbers, no matter how big.